# Can't connect to WiFi 16.04 - Additional Drivers not found

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless, additional-drivers

I've recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my device (alongside Windows 10) and I cannot get it to connect to the internet via WiFi. I have tried using the cable for an Ethernet connection but the Wifi option seem to be missing.
Now of course I did my research and all the solutions I have found proposed going to the "Additional Drivers" and change the settings there; problem is, I did go there and there are no drivers available for me to select from.
Is there any way for me to fix this? How?
Thanks in advance.

~~Edit
after running `sudo lshw -class network` the output was:

```
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:ab200000-ab207fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 07
       serial: 74:e6:e2:45:a5:64
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.108 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:47 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:ab100000-ab100fff memory:d2100000-d2103fff
```

Also, after `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I will see that article too, @Videonauth, thank you. (Also thanks for fixing up the display of my question). Hopefully the problem will be solved.

Comment: If its not solved [edit] your question to include what and where you got stuck on that and it will been send to the reopen review que. And you're certainly welcome.

Comment: Thankfully, it was solved, thanks for the recommended dublicate - it actually solved my problem. Have a great day!